# PHP 7 Soap Server runs out of memory at about 10MB (libxml XML_PARSE_HUGE issue?). How to fix this?

Tags: php, xml, soap, base64, libxml2

In our PHP7 application (running on Ubuntu 16 LTS) I run into an issue with large SOAP requests. Our PHP application is built on top of PHP's SoapServer. 
When I try to send a large file (+/- 10 MB) in a properly encoded SOAP message, passing it as a base64binary, I get the following error:
"XML error on line 2 col 14351283 byte 0 No memory".

All of the server's PHP settings are set to high allowances (far above 10 MB) and the machines have 32 GB of physical RAM.

I have searched on the Internet and I come across several similar reports, that are related to libxml requiring the XML_PARSE_HUGE directive in order to handle tall requests well. I believe this to be the reason why my requests return the above error.

However ... seemingly, as of PHP 5.x that issue SHOULD have been solved already since about mid 2014 ( see: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67427 ).

There are no global php.ini settings that I see for forcing libxml to use the XML_PARSE_HUGE directive and source-building a new libxml library is no option on those machines.

Does anyone know any/all of the following?:

1) Is my issue indeed due to the (missing) XML_PARSE_HUGE directive, causing the too large SOAP request to fail being decoded?

2) If the answer to question 1 is 'yes': does anyone know how I can get PHP's SoapServer to pass this XML_PARSE_HUGE directive?

3) If the answer to question 1 is 'no': does anyone know what else might cause this and how to solve it (other than creating a Soap RPC method that receives such large files in chunks and stitches them together)?